# problemas para hacer un paginado con laravel

Tags: laravel, paginación

estoy intentanto hacer un paginado en mi proyecto de laravel y en la controller tengo implementada la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$cargos = Candidatura::where('hermano_id', '=', $regMiembro->id)->paginate(10);

    return view('reg_miembros.show', compact('cargos'));
```

y en la vista implemente la tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered jambo_table bulk_action">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="text-align: center;">A&ntilde;o</th>
                                                <th style="text-align: center;">Cargo</th>
                                                <th style="text-align: center;">Fecha Elecciones</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            @foreach($cargos as $cargo)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                                        {{ $cargo->getDatosCandidatura()->year }}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                                        {{ $cargo->getCargo()->cargo }}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                                                        {{ convertirFecha($cargo->getDatosCandidatura()->fecha_elecciones) }}
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                            {{ $cargos->links() }}
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

El problema consiste en que `{{ $cargos->links() }}` no me esta funcionando y no me muestra el navegador para avanzar en la tabla. Que pudiera ser el error

Comment: Probaste ponerlos fuera de la etiqueta `<table></table>`?

Comment: ¿Tienes mas de diez registro?

Comment: solamente tengo uno por el momento, pero eso tendra algo que ver??

Comment: si probe ponerlo fuera de  <table></table>

Comment: @albertolg89 Si no tienes mas de 10 no se mostrara, ve que sucede con once o mas registros

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tienes mas de 10 registros en esa tabla. Si no tienes mas de 10 entonces nunca se mostraran los links.